# What does " {% " mean in Javascript

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, google-maps-markers

I'm applying to a front-end test, that have a page that i might develop a responsive version. So i `git clone` they repository, run `npm install`, run `grunt` and when i finally open the html at browser i receive this error at console:

[image]

So i go find why this is happening, and i found this javascript:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             icon: {
                    url: '{% static "assets/images/marker_center.png" %}',
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 156),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(38, 95)
                    },
             position: pyrmont
            });
```

So i thought that's this `{%` was a sintaxe used at google maps api, but it isn't. It's not required, i can just write the path to the image and the page run without errors. My question is, why they put `{%` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code `{% static "PATH/TO/FILE"%}` is a variable used in a Grunt script or Python to be replaced with a path/URL to a file.

More info on static Python template variables in the [Python docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/).

Comment: Any idea for why the grunt isn't replacing this code?

Comment: It's a Python template tag for linking to a file saved in the STATIC ROOT. More info in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static).